# How to get if question is really edited or not by some one?

Tags: discussion

I was asked below question on magentoSE but after some times someone edited it, And when i see there is nothing changes in it. So when a question edited, the portion of editing should be marked as edit OR a note should be bottom of questions automatically added what is edit.

[magento-2-block-ordering-moving](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/151893/magento-2-block-ordering-moving-how-to-get-of-element-nameor-elements-list-an)

Comment: And what is your question here?

Comment: @Marius: as labeled discussion. Please read description...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is no need of explanation for that edit. user delete only 2 character you can see it here.

https://magento.stackexchange.com/posts/151893/revisions

Comment: Thanks buddy. To show me this which actually don't konws.